# django-cms context_processors.media has been deprecated

Tags: python, django, django-cms

This below command errors generates when i run my program with this command `python manage.py runserver`

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cms/context_processors.py:20: DeprecationWarning:

cms.context_processors.media has been deprecated in favor of 

cms.context_processors.cms_settings. Please update your configuration
          'configuration', DeprecationWarning)
```

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow instructions provided here http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/upgrade/3.0.html#cms-context-processors-media .

Your project probably has settings.py file which contains `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` variable (a list of content processors). This list contains `"cms.context_processors.media"`, it should be replaced with `"cms.context_processors.cms_settings"`.

Comment: I believe this is other problem, but was it showing before this change?

Comment: yes django page after few reloads of page returns this error and nothing is visible after this error generated

Comment: I don't know how to help you with this problem, I can only advice to use django debug toolbar with template context plugin to track down the issue.